# Debug php with Netbeans - Newbie source request

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, var-dump

I'm using var_dump. Everywhere. It's a mess. And slow. I would like to lock a variable, right-click, choose test, and it will show me the output results on each period or my script, on a IDE window. -

1) Does something like this exist on Netbeans ?

2) Regardless about what could the "best" thing here, am wondering, if anyone could advice me some books/resources on the subject: "Debugging for newbies" ?

Update:
I realise that netbeans does have some possible integration. The hard part, however, is that of find newbie resources considering that integration. I mean, I need to understand how the debug tool work. True. But I also need to understand how debug work (in broad general terms sort of speak). :)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

XDebug. For configuring it to work with Netbeans, see here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Answer (score 1):

1) The debug-solution for PHP is XDebug. It got all you need, like variable inspection eg.

2) Not long ago I was searching for that myself. So I know for pretty sure there is nothing like that. XDebug.org  and Google will help you.